# How to preserve newlines in text area submitted for email message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm sending an email through my rails app with the message in the email being entered by the user into a text_area. For some reason though when I receive the email message, the newlines are missing. How can I get those back when rendering the email template?

Here's the whole of my email template:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <%= @message %>
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `simple_format(@var)`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format